# React modal update item bug

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, modal-dialog, redux-toolkit

During the update process, it updates the information of the same id value every time, what could be the problem? for example, it updates the field with id number 3 on every update operation. I am using the index value in the loop for the update process

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSTaD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmykv.png)

```js
{cardItemData.map((cardItem, index) => (
<>
    <tr id={index}>
        <td>{cardItem.min}</td>
        <td>{cardItem.price}</td>
    </tr>

    <Modal
        titleId
        isOpen={modalState}
        setIsOpen
        isStaticBackdrop
        isScrollable
        isCentered
        size
        isAnimation>
        <ModalHeader
            className
            setIsOpen={() =>
                setModalState(false)
            }>
            <ModalTitle id>
                Update
            </ModalTitle>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-lg-4'>
                    <FormGroup
                        id='cardMinUp'
                        label={t(
                            'form.cardMin',
                        )}
                        isFloating>
                        <Input
                            type='number'
                            placeholder={t(
                                'form.cardMin',
                            )}
                            isValid={
                                formik.isValid
                            }
                            value={
                                formik
                                    .values
                                    .cardMinUp
                            }
                            onChange={
                                formik.handleChange
                            }
                            isTouched={
                                formik
                                    .touched
                                    .cardMinUp
                            }
                            invalidFeedback={
                                formik
                                    .errors
                                    .cardMinUp
                            }
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
                <div className='col-lg-4'>
                    <FormGroup
                        id='cardPriceUp'
                        label={t(
                            'form.cardPrice',
                        )}
                        isFloating>
                        <Input
                            type='number'
                            placeholder={t(
                                'form.cardPrice',
                            )}
                            isValid={
                                formik.isValid
                            }
                            value={
                                formik
                                    .values
                                    .cardPriceUp
                            }
                            onChange={
                                formik.handleChange
                            }
                            isTouched={
                                formik
                                    .touched
                                    .cardPriceUp
                            }
                            invalidFeedback={
                                formik
                                    .errors
                                    .cardPriceUp
                            }
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
                <div className='col-lg-4 mt-2'>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => {
                            dispatch(
                                agencySlice.editUpdateCardItem(
                                    {
                                        id: index,
                                        min: formik
                                            .values
                                            .cardMinUp,
                                        price: formik
                                            .values
                                            .cardPriceUp,
                                    },
                                ),
                            );

                            setModalState(
                                false,
                            );
                        }}
                        className='me-3'
                        icon='plus'
                        isOutline
                        color='info'>
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
</>
))}
```

Comment: Please explain you problem well: what's supposed to happen & what actually happens. Post an well formatted short code example. You can leave out unnecessary details like `className` & styling. You can use the card's id as key for the `<tr>`

Comment: In order to dispatch agencySlice.editUpdateCardItem, I send the map index value as the id value, but during the updating of each element, the id value is constant 3 and does not change dynamically.

Comment: Are there any warnings in the console about missing key ? Also add `react-redux` tag to you question to get better help.

Comment: no not. My problem is that it updates the same element as fixed, not the selected item in the update process

Answer (score 0):

I think I have guessed the problem & it's a basic JavaScript problem.
You are using `index` to see the clicked button's card's "id".

You should instead use `event.currentTarget` to access the clicked button, as the index is unreliable for an event handler.

```
<Button data-index={index}>
    onClick={handleButtonClick}
    className='me-3'
    >
        Save
</Button>

// move the event handler into the top level of the function component
let handleClick = (event)=> {
    // access the index of the clicked (card's) button.
    let index = +event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    dispatch(
        agencySlice.editUpdateCardItem({
            id: index,
            min: formik.values.cardMinUp,
            price: formik.values.cardPriceUp,
        })
    );
    setModalState(false);
};
```